Flowing Text from one Narrative Field to Another on Different Page (copy & paste OR write in)
Ok so I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to either copy and paste a narrative from word into a fillable PDF that will span two separate narrative fields that happen to span two pages.  currently doing research and using this script:
var x=this.getField ("Narrative 1");
if (event.fieldFull) {
getField("Narrative 2").setFocus();
}
the issue is when I type in the PDF, it does span across to the next narrative box.  However, if I need to edit text in Narrative 1 box, it puts the text at end in Narrative 2 because Narrative 1 is full (IMO).  Any fix for that?
Other issue is it would be nice to copy and paste narrative into Narrative 1 box and have overflow go into Narrative 2 box on next page?  thanks in advance for help
